# Synchronization of outlook messages attributes (Flag, IsRead) and deletion status

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

According to this documentation [Synchronize messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#synchronize-messages) API users have ability to synchronize messages with pretty simple skipToken mechanics. And it works well for fetching new messages in folders.

**But!** What I'm also interested is how to sync flags and status like is message read or not.
For example I synced all messages from Inbox folder. After that user goes to his Outlook account and reads message and set some flag for this message.

How can I get this info? Should I resync all messages to get only those changes?

Also how I get notion about message removal? If some user deleted message from inbox, how I get to know which message was deleted without fetching all messages again?

Comment: What platform are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) and move away from using the Outlook Rest API as it has been deemphasized with no more effort being put into the developer experience.

Use [Microsoft Graph to synchronize and track changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) by using the Delta query feature.

An initial sync call will happen with a Delta query. Make sure you select the properties you care about:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/AQMkADNkNAAAgEMAAAA/messages/delta?$select=subject,sender,isRead
Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=50
```

If the response has an `@odata.nextlink` in the response JSON object, GET that URL to the next page of results.

If the response has an `@odata.deltaLink` in the response JSON object, cache that URL until the next time you want to check for changes.

Comment: What "AQMkADNkNAAAgEMAAAA" value is this? and How can I get all mail in the first sync?